# How to tell whether Hamiltonian has rotational invariance? Conservation of angular momentum?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, symmetry, hamiltonian, molecular-dynamics

If a system contains isotropic exchange interaction and uniaxial anisotropy in the $z$-direction,

[image]

does this Hamiltonian satisfy rotational invariance of the $z$-direction so that the spin angular momentum in the $z$-direction is conserved?Is the spin angular momentum in the x,y-direction not conserved because it does not satisfy rotational invariance of the x,y-direction?Similarly, if a magnetic field is applied in the $z$-direction, is the result the same as above?

Comment: "rotation in the $x$ direction" is ambiguous. Do you mean "rotation about the $x$ axis"? Also: $I, j$ are particle labels?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. Rotation in the x direction means rotating around the x axis. The first term in the Hamiltonian quantity is the exchange interaction, J is the exchange coefficient, and i,j are the atomic labels. The second term is z-axis anisotropy.

Comment: My question is, does the rotational invariance of the Hamiltonian around the z-axis (or x,y-axis) mean rotating the spin around the z-axis (or x,y-axis) and then the Hamiltonian remains unchanged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the classical framework, the exchange interaction term **S**$_{i}$ $\cdot$ **S**$_{j}$ satisfies the rotation invariance of the x,y,z-direction, but the uniaxial anisotropy term ${(S_{i}^{z})}^2$ breaks the rotational invariance of the x- and y-directions, so the total Hamiltonian quantity satisfies rotational invariance of the z-direction only, with conservation of spin angular momentum in the z-direction. The same is true for adding a magnetic field in the z direction.